# Catalina 6.x Start and stop bacome final in 8.x

Tags: java, catalina

x I have overriden the LifecycleBase.start() method like the following. but in Catalina 8.x this method has become final. 
Could anyone tell me how to solve this Problem please.
Here is the sourcecode

```
 public void start() throws LifecycleException
{       
    super.start();

    if(condition)
    {
        File checkDataFile = new File(DataFilePath);
        if(containerLog.isDebugEnabled())
            containerLog.debug("checking secureDataFile: " + checkDataFile.getAbsolutePath());

        another code ...
    }
    else
    {
        throw new LifecycleException("illegal arguments");
    }
}

public void stop() throws LifecycleException
{
    // sync via realm-object -> so the stop-event has to wait for active threads finishing their operations
    synchronized(this)
    {
        super.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [startInternal()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/util/LifecycleBase.html#startInternal()) and [stopInternal()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/util/LifecycleBase.html#stopInternal()),  both methods are `abstract protected` and are called respectively by `start()` and `stop()` .

Of course don't call `super.start()` and `super.stop()` or you are in for a `StackOverflowError`, since `start()` and `stop()`are already calling your custom "internal" methods.

Also read carefully the contract from these two methods :

> **startInternal()**
>
> Sub-classes must ensure that the state is changed to org.apache.catalina.LifecycleState.STARTING during the execution of
>   this method. Changing state will trigger the
>   org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle.START_EVENT event. If a component fails
>   to start it may either throw a org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException
>   which will cause it's parent to fail to start or it can place itself
>   in the error state in which case stop() will be called on the failed
>   component but the parent component will continue to start normally

and

> **stopInternal()**
>
> Sub-classes must ensure that the state is changed to
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleState.STOPPING during the execution of
>   this method. Changing state will trigger the
>   org.apache.catalina.Lifecycle.STOP_EVENT event.

If you want to see what happens with more details, look at the code of
 one of the latest versions of
 [org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.24/org/apache/catalina/util/LifecycleBase.java#LifecycleBase.start%28%29) .